# Hibernate Criteria for elements inside a Set

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have one entity that contains a set of another entity.

Entity1 contains Set entityTwos

I want to create a search criteria for an "id" field inside entityTwos.

I searched, but didn't get any answers. Anybody have an idea?

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was easy. Something like:

```
criteria.createAlias("entityTwos", "entityTwo");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("entityTwo.id", ...));
```